# SVG Path animation running very slowly, lagging the rest of my tabs in Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, animation, anime.js

My code works but it is slowing down all my other tabs in Chrome. Is there a way to optimize this?

Is it because of the size of my SVG file? I had to delete a lot of lines to make it even fit into this code snippet, the actual file is quite a bit larger.

Is there a specific way I need to optimize my SVG in order to have it run more smoothly, in particular with animation libraries such as anime.js?

```js
var pathEls = document.querySelectorAll('path');
for (var i = 0; i < pathEls.length; i++) {
  var pathEl = pathEls[i];
  var offset = anime.setDashoffset(pathEl);
  pathEl.setAttribute('stroke-dashoffset', offset);
  anime({
    targets: pathEl,
    strokeDashoffset: [offset, 0],
    duration: anime.random(2000, 6000),
    delay: anime.random(0, 500),
    loop: true,
    direction: 'alternate',
    easing: 'linear',
    autoplay: true,
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  background: rgb(165, 155, 254);
  background: linear-gradient(
    90deg,
    rgba(165, 155, 254, 0.13903264331210186) 0%,
    rgba(159, 149, 202, 1) 0%,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.32374601910828027) 100%
  );
  height: 100vh;
  width: 4000px;
  margin: 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;

}
.anim,
.anim svg {
  position: relative;
  width: 4000px;
  height: 1000px;
}
.anim path {
  stroke-width: 1.3;
}

.bg-orig {
  position: absolute;
  width: 4000px;
  height: 1000px;
  z-index: -10;
  opacity: 0.1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="node_modules/animejs/lib/anime.min.js"></script>
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/animejs@3.2.0/lib/anime.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- <img class="bg-orig" src="./bg.svg" /> -->

    <div class="anim">
      <svg
        class="svg-img"
        id="Layer_1"
        data-name="Layer 1"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        viewBox="0 0 3932.32 520.41"
      >
        <defs>
          <linearGradient id="linear" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#a4d3e1" />
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#ffa6bd" />
          </linearGradient>
        </defs>
        <g fill="none">
          <title>SB_SCULPTURE_DRAFT_VECTOR</title>
          <path
            class="path"
            d="M954.42,428l-6.11,6.12H767.16L761,428,746.11,413.1l-22.82-22.82L705.42,372.4,705,372H561l-.42.41-17.88,17.88-4,4H506.27l-4-4L499,387V326.7l-.42-.42L468.26,296a8.16,8.16,0,0,0,1.34-4.5h0a8.11,8.11,0,0,0-1.67-4.95,9.28,9.28,0,0,0-.71-.82,8.2,8.2,0,0,0-5.78-2.39h0a8.15,8.15,0,0,0-5.77,2.38,8,8,0,0,0-.71.83,8.12,8.12,0,0,0-1.68,4.95h0a8.16,8.16,0,0,0,8.16,8.16h0a8.1,8.1,0,0,0,4.86-1.61l29.81,29.81v60.26l.41.42,1.73,1.72,6.43,6.43.41.42H539.9l.42-.42,6.43-6.43,15.46-15.46H703.82l15.46,15.46L742.1,413.1,757,428l8.54,8.54.41.42h183.5l.42-.42,8.54-8.54,1.2-1.2,13.91.14L974.6,428l8.86,8.85.41.42h35.51l1.11,1.5,2,2.73H762.31l-2.74-2.73L748.8,428,733.87,413.1l-22.82-22.82L700.87,380.1l-.42-.41H567.19l-.41.41-10.19,10.18-11.86,11.87H499.94l-9-9V334.68l-.42-.41L460,303.78l-.42-.42H448.66a7.67,7.67,0,1,0,0,2.84h9.78l29.66,29.66V394.3l.41.41,9.85,9.85.42.42h47.13l.41-.41,14.29-14.29,7.76-7.76H699.28l7.76,7.76,22.82,22.82L744.79,428l10.76,10.77,5.16,5.16.42.41h267l-1.68-2.26L1024,438.8l-2.79-3.76-.43-.58H985.05L978.62,428l-3.47-3.47-.41-.41h-.58l-15.1-.15h-.6l-.41.41Zm-493-130.84a5.68,5.68,0,0,1-5.68-5.67h0a5.66,5.66,0,0,1,1.67-4,5.2,5.2,0,0,1,1.24-.94,5.56,5.56,0,0,1,2.77-.73h0a5.53,5.53,0,0,1,2.77.73,5.2,5.2,0,0,1,1.24.94,5.66,5.66,0,0,1,1.67,4h0a5.68,5.68,0,0,1-5.68,5.68h0Z"
            transform="translate(-30.27 -261.21)"
            stroke="url(#linear)"
          />
          <path
            class="path"
            stroke="url(#linear)"
            d="M212.34,602.05a8.9,8.9,0,0,0,2.06-1.53,9.18,9.18,0,0,0,2.36-4.07h9.07l.42-.42,2-1.95,0,0,7.29-7.3,7.4-7.4,62-.07,7.47,7.47,3,3,.41.42h92.32l3.86,3.86,8,8,1.07,1.07,14.4,14.4.05.05.36.36H459.6l.36-.36.05-.05,5.76-5.75a7.68,7.68,0,0,0,12-6.34,7.53,7.53,0,0,0-.78-3.38,7.68,7.68,0,1,0-13.23,7.71l-5.34,5.34H437l-11.77-11.78L424,602.05l-8-8-6.28-6.28-.42-.42H317l-.62-.62-8.65-8.65-1.24-1.24-.18-.17-.23-.24h-.59l-63.14.08h-.6l-.15.16-.26.24-1.16,1.17-8.65,8.65-6.85,6.85h-7.6a9.08,9.08,0,0,0-2.65-6h0a8.77,8.77,0,0,0-1-.89A9.09,9.09,0,0,0,208,585h0a9,9,0,0,0-5.37,1.77,10.73,10.73,0,0,0-1,.88h0a9.08,9.08,0,0,0-2.66,6.43h0v0h0a9.05,9.05,0,0,0,2.65,6.39,8.81,8.81,0,0,0,2.08,1.55,9,9,0,0,0,4.34,1.12h0A9,9,0,0,0,212.34,602.05ZM208,600.34a6.27,6.27,0,0,1-6.24-6.23h0v0h0a6.27,6.27,0,0,1,1.84-4.42h0a6.23,6.23,0,0,1,4.4-1.83h0a6.24,6.24,0,0,1,4.42,1.83h0a6.21,6.21,0,0,1,1.83,4.4h0v0h0a6.25,6.25,0,0,1-6.24,6.25h0Z"
            transform="translate(-30.27 -261.21)"
          />
          <path
            class="path"
            stroke="url(#linear)"
            d="M193.89,641.73A7.69,7.69,0,0,0,201,631.14l5.55-5.54,8-8,15.52-15.52,8-8,6-6h60.5l6,6,5.26,5.26.42.42H396l2.3,2.29L411,614.77l2.8,2.8,8,8L434,637.83l.41.41h27.33l.41-.41,12.23-12.23,8-8,7-7a9.15,9.15,0,0,0,3.28.62h0a9.73,9.73,0,0,0,2.6-.38l-6.8,6.8-8,8L460.3,645.87H435.21L414.93,625.6l-8-8-9-9-.42-.41H349.06l-.41.39-9.43,9L337,619.71H305.49l-.42.42-5.46,5.47-6.73,6.72H279.13l-.42.43-15.37,15.61-5.9,6L252.83,659h-5.27a7.67,7.67,0,1,0,0,2.84H254l.42-.43h0l7-7.09,5.9-6,13-13.2H294l.43-.42,9.14-9.14,3.05-3.06H338.1l.42-.39,4.79-4.58,6.88-6.57h46.14l6.56,6.57,8,8,22.7,22.7.06.06.35.35h27.45l.35-.35.06-.06,22.7-22.7,8-8,4.94-4.94h11.76l.41-.41,10.17-10.17,8-8,3.85-3.85h47.19l.41-.41,3.06-3.06,8.65-8.65,1.42-1.41.65-.66.89-.88h59.27l.88.88.66.66,1.41,1.41,8.65,8.65,7.32,7.32,1,1,.42.42h56.11l6.58,6.58L749,614.79H628l-.42.42-2.36,2.36-8,8L594.71,648H471l-.33.33-.08.09-5.91,5.91L444,675.1H432.63a7.68,7.68,0,0,0-15.22,1.42,8,8,0,0,0,.08,1.1,7.68,7.68,0,0,0,15.14.32h12.51l.32-.32.09-.1,23.16-23.16,3.49-3.49H595.88l.42-.41,2.09-2.1,22.77-22.76,8-8H755.85l-.06-.06-2.36-2.36-13.15-13.16-8-8-1-1-.42-.42H674.75l-5.87-5.87-8.65-8.65-1.42-1.41-.65-.66-2.7-2.7-.61-.61-.41-.41H592.81l-.42.41-.6.61-2.7,2.7-.66.66L587,578.11l-8.65,8.65-.65.64H530.53l-.41.42-6.26,6.26-8,8-7.74,7.74H497.57a9,9,0,0,0,1.64-1.3,9.12,9.12,0,0,0,2.67-6.42h0v0h0A9.11,9.11,0,0,0,492.8,593h0a9.13,9.13,0,0,0-6.4,2.66h0a9.06,9.06,0,0,0-2.66,6.43h0v0h0a9.06,9.06,0,0,0,2.65,6.4h0a6.42,6.42,0,0,0,.61.56l-8.53,8.53-8,8-9.82,9.81H435.64l-9.81-9.81-8-8-3.13-3.13-12.38-12.39-4.72-4.71-.42-.42h-79.7l-2.84-2.84-7.32-7.32-1.12-1.11-.42-.42H242.9l-.41.42-1.12,1.11-7.32,7.32-8,8-15.51,15.52-8,8-3.12,3.12a7.69,7.69,0,0,0-5.52-2.34"
            transform="translate(-30.27 -261.21)"
          />
          <path
            class="path"
            stroke="url(#linear)"
            d="M492.77,608.32a6.11,6.11,0,0,1-3-.77l-.68-.67L489,607a6.48,6.48,0,0,1-.62-.54h0a6.21,6.21,0,0,1-1.83-4.4h0v0h0a6.21,6.21,0,0,1,1.84-4.42h0a6.27,6.27,0,0,1,4.4-1.84h0a6.28,6.28,0,0,1,6.25,6.24h0v0h0a6.19,6.19,0,0,1-1.84,4.41,6.27,6.27,0,0,1-4.4,1.84h0Z"
            transform="translate(-30.27 -261.21)"
          />
          <path
            stroke="url(#linear)"
            d="M292.38,567l9.05-9h44.4l.42-.42,3.83-3.83,1.42-1.42,9.11-9.1h9.45a7.68,7.68,0,1,0,0-2.84H359.44l-.41.41-2.79,2.79-8.74,8.74-1.42,1.42-1.41,1.41H300.25l-.41.42L288.37,567l-1.66,1.66H233L231.42,567,226,561.08a7.62,7.62,0,0,0,1.51-4.57,7.58,7.58,0,0,0-1.29-4.25,7.69,7.69,0,0,0-13.53,1.42,7.58,7.58,0,0,0-.54,2.83,7.68,7.68,0,0,0,11.77,6.5l3.68,4,3.75,4,.42.45h56.16l.41-.41Z"
            transform="translate(-30.27 -261.21)"
          />
          <path
            class="path"
            stroke="url(#linear)"
            d="M1451.55,485l9-9.05H1505l.41-.41,3.84-3.83,1.42-1.42,9.1-9.1h9.46a7.68,7.68,0,1,0,0-2.84h-10.62l-.42.41-2.78,2.79-8.75,8.74-1.42,1.42-1.41,1.41h-44.41l-.42.41L1447.53,485l-1.66,1.66h-53.75l-1.53-1.66-5.47-5.89a7.68,7.68,0,0,0,1-7.4,8,8,0,0,0-.74-1.42,7.68,7.68,0,0,0-12.79,0,8,8,0,0,0-.74,1.42,7.58,7.58,0,0,0-.54,2.83,7.69,7.69,0,0,0,11.77,6.5l3.68,4,3.74,4,.43.46h56.15l.42-.41Z"
            transform="translate(-30.27 -261.21)"
            stroke="#DB1D1D"
          />
          <path
            stroke="url(#linear)"
            d="M110.54,659.18l9-9H164l.42-.42,3.83-3.83,1.42-1.42,9.11-9.1h9.45a7.68,7.68,0,1,0,0-2.84H177.6l-.41.41-2.79,2.79-8.75,8.74-1.41,1.42-1.41,1.41H118.41l-.41.41-11.47,11.47-1.66,1.66H51.12l-1.54-1.66-5.46-5.89a7.62,7.62,0,0,0,1.51-4.57,7.79,7.79,0,0,0-.54-2.83,7.4,7.4,0,0,0-.75-1.42,7.67,7.67,0,0,0-12.78,0,7.4,7.4,0,0,0-.75,1.42,7.58,7.58,0,0,0-.54,2.83A7.69,7.69,0,0,0,42,655.22l3.68,4,3.75,4.05.42.45h56.16l.41-.41Z"
            transform="translate(-30.27 -261.21)"
          />
          <path
            stroke="url(#linear)"
            d="M953.67,413.1l-12.74,12.74h-171L757.2,413.1l-22.82-22.82-25.56-25.57-.42-.41H542.81l-28.14-28.14V316.54l-.42-.42L490.93,292.8V275.58l-.41-.41-8.5-8.5L477,261.62l-.41-.41H445.13l-.41.41-5.06,5.05-5.91,5.92H428a7.7,7.7,0,0,0-5.26-5.92,7.86,7.86,0,0,0-2.28-.34,7.76,7.76,0,0,0-2.28.34,7.68,7.68,0,1,0,9.82,8.75h6.93l.32-.32.09-.09,8.34-8.34,2.64-2.64h29.05l2.64,2.64,10.08,10.09V294l.42.42,23.32,23.32v19.62l.41.41,29,29,.41.41h165.6l23.15,23.15,22.81,22.82L768.11,428l.24.23.41.42H942.1l.42-.42.23-.23,14.93-14.93,5.35-5.34h15.16l5.34,5.34,9.63,9.62.41.42H1131.4l.41-.42,9.63-9.62,1-1h27.45v-2.83h-28.64l-.41.41-3.46,3.46-7.2,7.2H994.75l-7.2-7.2-7.77-7.77-.41-.41H961.85l-.42.41Z"
            transform="translate(-30.27 -261.21)"
          />
          <path
            stroke="url(#linear)"
            d="M578.19,403.73a7.68,7.68,0,1,0,14-4.33l4.88-4.88h61.7l6.73,6.72a7.58,7.58,0,0,0-1.34,4.33,7.67,7.67,0,0,0,6.18,7.53,7.48,7.48,0,0,0,3,0,7.68,7.68,0,1,0-5.81-13.87l-7.15-7.14-.41-.41H595.91l-.42.41-5.29,5.3a7.68,7.68,0,0,0-12,6.34Z"
            transform="translate(-30.27 -261.21)"
          />
          <path
            stroke="url(#linear)"
            d="M452,730.53a7.67,7.67,0,0,0-6.26-7.55v-8.27l20-20,17.07-17.07,11-11H597.6l.42-.41,11.87-11.87,6-6,12.68-12.68h82.21l6.67,6.67a9.12,9.12,0,0,0-2.27,6h0v0h0a9.06,9.06,0,0,0,2.26,6,5.33,5.33,0,0,0,.4.42,9,9,0,0,0,6.42,2.67h0a9,9,0,0,0,6.4-2.65c.15-.14.28-.29.42-.44a9,9,0,0,0,2.25-6h0a9.06,9.06,0,0,0-2.65-6.41h0a9.13,9.13,0,0,0-6.43-2.67h0a9.15,9.15,0,0,0-4.59,1.26l-7.28-7.27-.42-.42H627.39l-.41.42-15.11,15.1-6,6-9.45,9.45H492.65l-.41.41-13.39,13.39-17.07,17.07-18.43,18.43-.42.42V723a7.68,7.68,0,1,0,9.1,7.55ZM724.28,642.1A6.22,6.22,0,0,1,728.7,644h0a6.27,6.27,0,0,1,1.84,4.41h0a6.27,6.27,0,0,1-1.84,4.41,6.37,6.37,0,0,1-2.62,1.57,6.62,6.62,0,0,1-1.79.27h0a6.24,6.24,0,0,1-4.41-1.84,6.22,6.22,0,0,1-1.84-4.4h0v0h0a6.19,6.19,0,0,1,1.84-4.42h0a6.26,6.26,0,0,1,4.39-1.84h0Z"
            transform="translate(-30.27 -261.21)"
          />
          <path
            stroke="url(#linear)"
            d="M325,694.69a7.62,7.62,0,0,0-1-6.23l9.87-9.42.44-.42V646.35L356,625.6l1-.91h9.08a6.91,6.91,0,0,0,.15.91,9,9,0,0,0,2.44,4.48h0a9.08,9.08,0,0,0,6.43,2.66h0A9.08,9.08,0,0,0,384,625.6a8.69,8.69,0,0,0,.21-1.92h0v0h0a9.06,9.06,0,0,0-2.34-6.07l-.32-.33a9.08,9.08,0,0,0-6.42-2.67h0a9,9,0,0,0-6.39,2.66h0c-.11.11-.22.22-.32.34a9,9,0,0,0-2.16,4.28H355.87l-.41.39L352,625.6l-20,19.12-.44.42v32.27l-.21.21-9.22,8.8a7.68,7.68,0,1,0,2.92,8.27Zm43.88-71h0a6.23,6.23,0,0,1,1.84-4.41h0a6.29,6.29,0,0,1,3-1.66,6,6,0,0,1,1.42-.17h0a6.27,6.27,0,0,1,6.25,6.24h0v0h0a6.43,6.43,0,0,1-.3,1.92,6.3,6.3,0,0,1-5.94,4.32h0a6.23,6.23,0,0,1-4.42-1.84h0a6.19,6.19,0,0,1-1.83-4.4h0Z"
            transform="translate(-30.27 -261.21)"
          />
          <path
            stroke="url(#linear)"
            d="M1613.26,635.38a7.9,7.9,0,0,0,2,.27,7.62,7.62,0,0,0,4.19-1.25l9.43,9.87.41.44h32.27l20.76,21.74.91.95v9.08a9.09,9.09,0,0,0-5.4,2.6h0a9.09,9.09,0,0,0-2.67,6.42h0v0h0a9.12,9.12,0,0,0,7.16,8.87,9.33,9.33,0,0,0,1.92.2h0a9.06,9.06,0,0,0,6.08-2.34l.32-.31a9.06,9.06,0,0,0,2.67-6.43h0v0h0a9,9,0,0,0-2.65-6.4h0l-.34-.32a9.17,9.17,0,0,0-4.28-2.16V666.28l-.39-.42-3.36-3.51-19.13-20-.42-.43h-32.26l-.21-.22-8.81-9.22a7.67,7.67,0,0,0-6.23-12.16,7.48,7.48,0,0,0-2,.28,7.68,7.68,0,0,0,0,14.81Zm71,43.87h0a6.25,6.25,0,0,1,4.42,1.84h0a6.27,6.27,0,0,1,1.67,3,6.66,6.66,0,0,1,.17,1.43h0v0h0a6.17,6.17,0,0,1-.17,1.44,6.31,6.31,0,0,1-1.67,3,6.22,6.22,0,0,1-4.41,1.83h0a6.08,6.08,0,0,1-1.92-.3,6.29,6.29,0,0,1-4.33-5.94h0v0h0a6.23,6.23,0,0,1,1.84-4.41h0a6.14,6.14,0,0,1,2.49-1.52,6,6,0,0,1,1.91-.31h0Z"
            transform="translate(-30.27 -261.21)"
          />
          <path
            class="path"
            stroke="url(#linear)"
            d="M766.64,552.26l-1,1H595.21l-1-1L575,533l-.41-.42h-33l-.42.42L522,552.26l-1.42,1.42-2.17,2.17H471.61l-.43.5L465,563.22a9.06,9.06,0,0,0-5.2-1.65h0a9,9,0,0,0-6.4,2.66,9,9,0,0,0-2.66,6.43h0v0h0a9,9,0,0,0,1.76,5.35c.16.22.34.44.53.66s.24.26.36.39a10.09,10.09,0,0,0,1.23,1,9,9,0,0,0,5.19,1.64h0a9.12,9.12,0,0,0,6.4-2.65l.38-.4c.19-.22.36-.44.53-.66a9,9,0,0,0,1.76-5.36h0v0h0a9,9,0,0,0-1.84-5.46l5.84-6.49h46.67l.41-.41,4.6-4.6,1.42-1.42,16.8-16.8h30.6l16.8,16.8,1.42,1.42,2,2,.41.41H766.83l.42-.41,2-2,1.42-1.42,19.56-19.57H1063l6.4,6.4H788.73l-.41.42-12.76,12.75-1.42,1.42-6.95,7H595.82l-7-7-1.42-1.42-11.53-11.53-.42-.41h-32l-.41.41-11.53,11.53-1,1-.42.41h0v5.4A9.07,9.07,0,0,0,522.3,567a8.27,8.27,0,0,0-.07,1.11h0v0h0a9.06,9.06,0,0,0,1.66,5.22,10,10,0,0,0,1,1.17,9.25,9.25,0,0,0,2,1.53,9.7,9.7,0,0,0,1.47.66,9.12,9.12,0,0,0,2.92.48h0a9,9,0,0,0,4.39-1.14,9,9,0,0,0,2-1.52,8.67,8.67,0,0,0,1-1.18,9.1,9.1,0,0,0,1.67-5.24h0v0h0a10.15,10.15,0,0,0-.07-1.1,9,9,0,0,0-2.59-5.3h0a9,9,0,0,0-4.79-2.51v-4.3l1.17-1.17,1.42-1.42,9.1-9.11h29.67l9.11,9.11,1.42,1.42,9.38,9.38.41.41H768.37l.41-.41,9.38-9.38,1.42-1.42,10.33-10.33H1072.8l-2.67-4.35,3.66,1.93-9.23-9.24-.42-.42H789l-.41.42ZM459.82,564.4a6.27,6.27,0,0,1,4.25,1.68l.16.16.13.13a7.34,7.34,0,0,1,.51.6,6.32,6.32,0,0,1,1.2,3.67h0v0h0a6.25,6.25,0,0,1-.6,2.66,6.33,6.33,0,0,1-1.24,1.75A6.59,6.59,0,0,1,463,576a6.22,6.22,0,0,1-3.19.89h0a7.08,7.08,0,0,1-1.67-.23,6.66,6.66,0,0,1-1.52-.66,6.33,6.33,0,0,1-1.22-.95,6.27,6.27,0,0,1-1.83-4.4h0v0h0a6.28,6.28,0,0,1,6.23-6.26h0ZM533,562.05a6.24,6.24,0,0,1,2.78,1.62h0a6.26,6.26,0,0,1,1.73,3.3,6.72,6.72,0,0,1,.1,1.1h0v0h0a6.25,6.25,0,0,1-1.84,4.42,6.7,6.7,0,0,1-1,.82,6.25,6.25,0,0,1-3.39,1h0a6.2,6.2,0,0,1-3.4-1,7.31,7.31,0,0,1-1-.83,6.24,6.24,0,0,1-1.84-4.39h0v0h0a6.84,6.84,0,0,1,.1-1.11,6.35,6.35,0,0,1,1.75-3.31,6.24,6.24,0,0,1,3.22-1.71v.22H533Z"
            transform="translate(-30.27 -261.21)"
          />
          
          <path
            stroke="url(#linear)"
            d="M3229.51,529.89H3331l11.9,11.9.41.41H3487L3517,572.12l8.92,8.92,2.91,2.91.41.41h128.87l.42-.41,2.9-2.91,3.69-3.68a9,9,0,0,0,4.39,1.13h0a9.08,9.08,0,0,0,6.41-2.65h0a9.11,9.11,0,0,0,2.67-6.42h0v0h0a9.1,9.1,0,0,0-9.08-9.06h0a9.1,9.1,0,0,0-9.08,9.08h0v0h0a9.24,9.24,0,0,0,.42,2.7,9.07,9.07,0,0,0,2,3.49L3657.4,581l-.48.48H3530.39l-.48-.48-8.92-8.92-32.34-32.34-.42-.41h-143.7l-11.9-11.9-.41-.42H3228.33l-.41.42-23.28,23.28H2861.2l6.1-6.1h336.62l.42-.41L3227,521.58h104.82L3345.25,535l.42.42H3496l34.36,34.36.41.41h42.51l.41-.41L3584,559.48l1-1-1-1-9.38-9.38-.42-.41H3560.5L3533.83,521l-.41-.41H3470.1l10.09-10.09h45.35l.41-.42L3540,496h16.72l19,19,.42.42h63.17l.42-.42,12.82-12.82h58.13l.41-.41,8.82-8.82h24.17a9,9,0,0,0,2.55,5h0a9.08,9.08,0,0,0,6.43,2.66h0a9.06,9.06,0,0,0,6.4-2.65h0a9.08,9.08,0,0,0,2.66-6.43h0v0h0c0-.33,0-.65,0-1a8.47,8.47,0,0,0-.27-1.42,9.09,9.09,0,0,0-8.75-6.68h0a9.12,9.12,0,0,0-8.75,6.68,8.29,8.29,0,0,0-.21,1H3718.7l-.41.42h0l-8.8,8.8h-58.12l-.42.42-12.81,12.82h-60.83l-19-19-.41-.42h-19.08l-.41.42-14,14H3479l-.41.42L3465.68,521l-2.42,2.41h69l26.67,26.68.42.41h13.73l8,8-8.9,8.89H3532L3497.6,533l-.41-.42H3346.83l-13.43-13.43-.42-.41H3225.82l-.41.41-22.67,22.67H2866.11l-.41.42-8.93,8.93-2.43,2.43h351.48l.41-.42Zm440,45.77a6.06,6.06,0,0,1-2.26-.43l.09-.09-.22-.22-.78-.79-1-1-.48.47a6.22,6.22,0,0,1-1-1.48,6.41,6.41,0,0,1-.62-2.7h0v0h0a6.28,6.28,0,0,1,6.25-6.25h0a6.17,6.17,0,0,1,4.41,1.84,6.26,6.26,0,0,1,1.84,4.39h0v0h0a6.22,6.22,0,0,1-1.84,4.42h0a6.21,6.21,0,0,1-4.4,1.83h0Zm77.29-84.11h0a6.37,6.37,0,0,1,.08-1,6.24,6.24,0,0,1,.4-1.42,6.16,6.16,0,0,1,1.36-2,6.27,6.27,0,0,1,4.4-1.84h0a6.23,6.23,0,0,1,4.41,1.84,6.4,6.4,0,0,1,1.35,2,6.26,6.26,0,0,1,.41,1.42,6.15,6.15,0,0,1,.07,1h0v0h0a6.21,6.21,0,0,1-1.84,4.42h0a6.21,6.21,0,0,1-4.4,1.83h0a6.23,6.23,0,0,1-4.42-1.83h0a6.21,6.21,0,0,1-1.84-4.4h0Z"
            transform="translate(-30.27 -261.21)"
          />
          
          <path
            stroke="url(#linear)"
            d="M2352,647.19l-.41-.41H2000.15l2.43,2.42,8.93,8.94.41.41h.6l336,0,22.67,22.67.41.42h107.16l.42-.42,13.43-13.43H2643l.41-.42L2677.77,633h40.16l8.9,8.89-8,8h-13.73l-.42.42L2678,676.94h-69l2.42,2.42,12.92,12.92.41.42h45.35l14,14,.41.41h19.08l.41-.41,19-19h60.83l12.81,12.81.42.42h58.12l8.8,8.8,0,0,.41.41h25.35a7.9,7.9,0,0,0,.21,1,9.09,9.09,0,0,0,8.75,6.68h0a9.09,9.09,0,0,0,8.75-6.68,8.29,8.29,0,0,0,.27-1.42c0-.31,0-.64,0-1h0v0h0a9,9,0,0,0-2.66-6.42h0a9.07,9.07,0,0,0-6.4-2.66h0a9.08,9.08,0,0,0-6.43,2.66h0a9,9,0,0,0-2.55,5h-24.17l-8.82-8.81-.41-.42h-58.13l-12.82-12.81-.41-.43h-63.18l-.42.42-19,19h-16.72l-14-14.05-.41-.41H2626l-10.09-10.09h63.32l.41-.41,26.67-26.67H2720l.42-.41,9.38-9.39,1-1-1-1-10.31-10.32-.42-.41h-42.51l-.41.41-34.36,34.36H2491.48l-.42.42-13.43,13.43H2372.81l-22.66-22.67-.41-.41h-.6l-336,0-6.1-6.1h343.44l23.28,23.28.41.41H2478l.41-.41L2490.35,661H2634l.42-.4,32.34-32.35,8.92-8.92.48-.48h126.53l.48.48,5.44,5.44a9,9,0,0,0-2,3.48,8.92,8.92,0,0,0-.41,2.7h0v0h0a9.06,9.06,0,0,0,9.07,9.07h0a9.1,9.1,0,0,0,9.08-9.06h0v0h0a9.11,9.11,0,0,0-2.67-6.42h0a9,9,0,0,0-6.41-2.66h0a9.15,9.15,0,0,0-4.39,1.13l-3.68-3.68-2.91-2.9-.41-.42H2675l-.41.42-2.91,2.9-8.92,8.92-29.92,29.93h-143.7l-.41.41-11.9,11.89H2375.32Zm463.25-22.49h0a6.21,6.21,0,0,1,4.4,1.83h0a6.22,6.22,0,0,1,1.84,4.42h0v0h0a6.25,6.25,0,0,1-6.25,6.23h0A6.25,6.25,0,0,1,2809,631h0v0h0a6.16,6.16,0,0,1,1.61-4.18l.48.47,1-1,.78-.78.22-.23-.09-.09a6.06,6.06,0,0,1,2.26-.43Zm77.29,84.09h0a6.22,6.22,0,0,1,1.84-4.4h0a6.27,6.27,0,0,1,4.42-1.83h0a6.26,6.26,0,0,1,4.4,1.83h0a6.23,6.23,0,0,1,1.84,4.42h0v0h0a6,6,0,0,1-.07,1,6.11,6.11,0,0,1-.41,1.42,6.24,6.24,0,0,1-5.76,3.85h0a6.28,6.28,0,0,1-5.76-3.85,6.1,6.1,0,0,1-.4-1.42,6.27,6.27,0,0,1-.08-1h0Z"
            transform="translate(-30.27 -261.21)"
          />
          <path
            stroke="url(#linear)"
            d="M2852.76,483.51a9.11,9.11,0,0,0,2.58-5.23h149a7.68,7.68,0,0,0,15.09,0h157.5l.41-.42,2-2,6.36-6.36,2.7-2.71.66-.65,1.41-1.42,8.65-8.65.82-.81h108.76l.81.81,8.65,8.65,1.42,1.42.65.65,2.7,2.71,6.36,6.36,2.25,2.24.41.41h70.55l.42-.41,2.24-2.24,6.36-6.36,2.7-2.71.65-.65,1.42-1.42,1.92-1.92h143.44l1.92,1.92,1.42,1.42.65.65,2.71,2.71,6.36,6.36,3.36,3.36a7.67,7.67,0,0,0,1.09,9.93,7.65,7.65,0,0,0,10.5,0,7.68,7.68,0,0,0-9.58-11.94l-1.36-1.35-6.36-6.36-2.7-2.71-.65-.65-1.42-1.42-4.34-4.34-.42-.42h-145.8l-.41.42-4.34,4.34-1.42,1.42-.66.65-2.7,2.71-6.18,6.17h-68.19l-6.18-6.17-2.7-2.71-.66-.65-1.41-1.42-8.65-8.65-3.24-3.24-.41-.41H3198.78l-.42.41-3.23,3.24-8.65,8.65-1.42,1.42-.65.65-2.71,2.71-5.95,5.95H3019.43a7.66,7.66,0,0,0-5.41-5.95,7.51,7.51,0,0,0-4.27,0,7.66,7.66,0,0,0-5.41,5.95H2855.27a9,9,0,0,0-2.51-4.78,8.49,8.49,0,0,0-1.43-1.17,9,9,0,0,0-5-1.5h0a9,9,0,0,0-5,1.5,8.4,8.4,0,0,0-1.42,1.15,9,9,0,0,0-2.59,5.21,9.58,9.58,0,0,0-.08,1.21h0v0h0a9.08,9.08,0,0,0,9.08,9.07h0A9.09,9.09,0,0,0,2852.76,483.51Zm159.09-11.75a5.25,5.25,0,1,1-5.09,4.09A5.22,5.22,0,0,1,3011.85,471.76Zm-165.53,11.58a6.27,6.27,0,0,1-6.25-6.24h0v0h0a6.06,6.06,0,0,1,.12-1.21,6.27,6.27,0,0,1,6.12-5h0a6.25,6.25,0,0,1,4.41,1.84,5.93,5.93,0,0,1,1.58,3.2,6.51,6.51,0,0,1-1.58,5.65,6.22,6.22,0,0,1-4.4,1.84h0Z"
            transform="translate(-30.27 -261.21)"
          />
          
          <path
            stroke="url(#linear)"
            d="M3384.1,581l4.75,4.75.41.41h32.23l.41-.41,4.75-4.75,8.06-8.06h42.17l8.06,8.06,4.84,4.84-.28.33a8.86,8.86,0,0,0-1.49,2.67,9,9,0,0,0-.52,3h0v0h0a9,9,0,0,0,2.16,5.86l.49.54a9.08,9.08,0,0,0,6.43,2.66h0a9.08,9.08,0,0,0,6.41-2.65c.17-.18.34-.36.5-.55a9.06,9.06,0,0,0,2.16-5.88h0v0h0a9,9,0,0,0-2-5.68,8.54,8.54,0,0,0-.64-.71,9.06,9.06,0,0,0-6.42-2.67h0a9,9,0,0,0-4.57,1.24l-3-3-8.92-8.92-1.57-1.57-.41-.41h-44.52l-.42.41-1.57,1.57-8.92,8.92-2.32,2.33h-29.87l-2.32-2.33-8.92-8.92-17.57-17.57-.41-.41h-21.9l-11.91-11.9-.41-.41h-95.23l4.54-4.55h93.81l11.58,11.59.42.41H3361l22.84,22.84,6,6,.41.41h29l.41-.41,6-6,6.85-6.84H3488l6.84,6.84,8.92,8.92,5.17,5.17,2.67,2.67.6.6,8.33,8.33,6.21,6.21,5.16,5.16.42.42h55.78l.42-.42,5.15-5.16,3-3a9,9,0,0,0,5.38,1.77h0a9.1,9.1,0,0,0,6.4-2.65,9.15,9.15,0,0,0,2.67-6.43h0v0h0a9.09,9.09,0,0,0-1.37-4.76,9.25,9.25,0,0,0-1.29-1.63h0a9.32,9.32,0,0,0-1.23-1,9.08,9.08,0,0,0-5.19-1.63h0a9,9,0,0,0-6.4,2.66,9.12,9.12,0,0,0-2.67,6.41h0v0h0a9.15,9.15,0,0,0,1,4.12,8.57,8.57,0,0,0,.71,1.16l-5.05,5-2.74,2.74h-53.42l-2.74-2.74-6.21-6.21-7.82-7.82-1.11-1.11-2.67-2.67L3507.8,581l-8.92-8.92-9.27-9.26-.41-.42h-58l-.42.42-9.26,9.26-3.56,3.56H3391.4l-3.56-3.56-25.26-25.26-.42-.42H3343.3l-11.59-11.58-.42-.42h-96.14l-.42.42-7.38,7.39-2.42,2.41h100.89l11.9,11.9.41.41H3360l15.15,15.15Zm112.49,4.62a6.29,6.29,0,0,1,2.56.55,6.43,6.43,0,0,1,1.86,1.28,6.73,6.73,0,0,1,1,1.39,6.17,6.17,0,0,1,.79,3h0v0h0a6.25,6.25,0,0,1-1.84,4.42,6.28,6.28,0,0,1-4.4,1.84h0a6.28,6.28,0,0,1-4.42-1.84,6.21,6.21,0,0,1-1.83-4.4h0v0h0a6.35,6.35,0,0,1,.75-3,6.12,6.12,0,0,1,2.88-2.67,6.42,6.42,0,0,1,2.61-.55h0Zm105.52,14.27a6.27,6.27,0,0,1-4-1.42,5.89,5.89,0,0,1-.45-.42l0,0-.23-.25a6.27,6.27,0,0,1-1.57-4.12h0v0h0a6.23,6.23,0,0,1,1.84-4.41l.39-.36a6.25,6.25,0,0,1,4-1.47h0a6.25,6.25,0,0,1,4,1.47l.4.37h0a6.28,6.28,0,0,1,1.83,4.39h0v0h0a6.29,6.29,0,0,1-1.57,4.13l-.27.29a6.26,6.26,0,0,1-4.4,1.83h0Z"
            transform="translate(-30.27 -261.21)"
          />
          <path
            stroke="url(#linear)"
            d="M2878.17,457.05h0a9,9,0,0,0,.86-1,9.09,9.09,0,0,0,1.81-5.44h0v0h0a9.44,9.44,0,0,0-.19-1.85,9.11,9.11,0,0,0-8.89-7.22h0a9.11,9.11,0,0,0-8.87,7.22c0,.15-.06.3-.08.45h-8.72l-.45-.45-8-8-6-6h85.41l6,6,6.33,6.33,1.64,1.64,1.65,1.65.42.42h24.58l.42-.42,1.65-1.65,3.32-3.32,4.65-4.65,6-6h89.48l5.35,5.35.61.62,8,8,.41.42.42.41h115.27l.41-.41.42-.42,8-8,3.28-3.28a7.67,7.67,0,1,0-1.71-2.31l-5.58,5.59-6,6H3087.1l-6-6-.81-.81-7.58-7.58-.41-.42h-91.84l-.41.42-8.39,8.39-4.87,4.86-2.34,2.34h-22.23l-1.05-1.06-6.15-6.14-8.38-8.39-.41-.41h-93.45l2.42,2.42,6.38,6.38,8,8,2.87,2.87.42.42h9.89a9.2,9.2,0,0,0,1.7,4,9.86,9.86,0,0,0,.84,1,9.13,9.13,0,0,0,6.43,2.67h0A9.09,9.09,0,0,0,2878.17,457.05Zm-6.43-.17a6.19,6.19,0,0,1-3.08-.82,6.09,6.09,0,0,1-1.34-1,6.27,6.27,0,0,1-1.67-3,6.7,6.7,0,0,1,0-2.84l.12-.45a6.29,6.29,0,0,1,5.95-4.39h0a6.25,6.25,0,0,1,4.42,1.84,6.43,6.43,0,0,1,1.55,2.55,6.28,6.28,0,0,1,.28,1.85h0v0h0a6.24,6.24,0,0,1-1.84,4.42h0a6.09,6.09,0,0,1-1.34,1,6.22,6.22,0,0,1-3.06.82h0Z"
            transform="translate(-30.27 -261.21)"
          />
          <path
            stroke="url(#linear)"
            d="M2981.37,572.12a7.57,7.57,0,0,0,1.37-3.15h317.31l3.15,3.15,8.92,8.92,1.06,1.06.42.42h15.45a7.68,7.68,0,0,0,15.09,0h23.59l3.64,3.69,2.62,2.67,1.59,1.61,7.2,7.32,1.49,1.51.41.43h32.84l4.28,4.27,10.77,10.77.54.54.42.42h79.12l14,14,1,1,.42.42h59.16l.41-.42,1-1,14.92-14.93,1.2-1.19h27l.41-.42,9.16-9.16,1.15-1.15a9.07,9.07,0,0,0,2.46,1.15,9.38,9.38,0,0,0,2.56.38h0a9.36,9.36,0,0,0,2.55-.38,9.09,9.09,0,0,0,6.16-6.21,8.94,8.94,0,0,0,.35-2.5h0v0h0a9.1,9.1,0,0,0-2.65-6.4h0a9.1,9.1,0,0,0-6.41-2.67h0a9.09,9.09,0,0,0-6.4,2.66h0a9,9,0,0,0-2.66,6.41h0v0h0a9.09,9.09,0,0,0,2,5.63l-.37.38L3637.3,604l-6.74,6.74h-27l-.42.42-3.61,3.61L3586,628.3h-56.8l-13.51-13.51-1.47-1.47-.41-.41h-79.12l-8.89-8.89-6.21-6.21-.49-.49-.42-.41h-32.84l-6.14-6.25-1.75-1.78-2.63-2.67-5.09-5.17-.92-.94-.42-.42h-24.77a7.68,7.68,0,0,0-15.09,0h-14.27l-7.56-7.56-5.57-5.57-.41-.41h-318.5a7.68,7.68,0,0,0-15.09,0H2822.93V569h144.72a7.68,7.68,0,0,0,13.72,3.15Zm666.11,29.45a6.27,6.27,0,0,1-3.18-.88l-1.83-1.84-.08.08a6.89,6.89,0,0,1-.64-1.12,6.23,6.23,0,0,1-.52-2.49h0v0h0a6.24,6.24,0,0,1,1.83-4.42,6.32,6.32,0,0,1,4.41-1.83h0a6.27,6.27,0,0,1,4.41,1.84,6.2,6.2,0,0,1,1.83,4.4h0v0h0a6.28,6.28,0,0,1-.52,2.5,6.35,6.35,0,0,1-1.31,1.92,6.27,6.27,0,0,1-4.4,1.84h0ZM3336.73,575.5a5.54,5.54,0,0,1,5.54,5.54h0a5.54,5.54,0,0,1-3.55,5.17,5.56,5.56,0,0,1-4,0,5.56,5.56,0,0,1-3.55-5.17h0A5.55,5.55,0,0,1,3336.73,575.5Zm-363.87-3.38a5.21,5.21,0,1,1,2.52.65A5.21,5.21,0,0,1,2972.86,572.12Z"
            transform="translate(-30.27 -261.21)"
          />
          <path
            stroke="url(#linear)"
            d="M3245.52,588.88l8.93,8.93,3.37,3.36.41.42h42.45l2.43,2.43,6.38,6.39.42.41h101.14l4,4L3428.18,628l.42.42h81.56l1.36,1.35,5.92,5.92.42.42h86.6l.42-.42,5.92-5.92,10.89-10.89h21.94l.41-.41,3.63-3.63L3658.44,604l6.21-6.21,8.93-8.93,2.67-2.67,5.17-5.17,7.14-7.14a7.69,7.69,0,1,0-2-2l-.23.23L3677.4,581l-5.17,5.17-2.67,2.67-8.93,8.93-6.21,6.21-10.77,10.77-1.2,1.2h-21.94l-.42.42-13.31,13.31-3.5,3.5H3519l-3.5-3.5-3.77-3.77-.42-.42h-81.56L3419,614.79l-6.4-6.39-.41-.42H3311.08l-4-4-4.85-4.85-.42-.42h-42.44l-.94-.94-8.93-8.93-2.67-2.67L3241.7,581l-2.18-2.18-.42-.42H2822.93v2.84h415l4.93,4.93Z"
            transform="translate(-30.27 -261.21)"
          />
          <path
            stroke="url(#linear)"
            d="M3251.66,606.72l.41.41h44.6l7.66,7.66,4.54,4.55.42.41H3410.9l7.3,7.31,2.67,2.66,2.84,2.85.42.41h81.42l9.74,9.74.42.41h91.53l.41-.41,3.45-3.45,9.55-9.55,5.66-5.65h21.63l.42-.43,8.85-8.85L3668,604l4.89-4.89h27.23L3705,604l10.77,10.77,14.93,14.93,9,9,.41.41h14.74l3.71,4.75a7.61,7.61,0,0,0-1.92,5.07,7.66,7.66,0,1,0,4.15-6.82l-4.14-5.29-.43-.55h-14.93l-6.58-6.58-14.93-14.93L3709,604l-6.21-6.21-1.11-1.1-.41-.42h-29.57l-.43.42-1.09,1.1L3664,604l-10.77,10.77-6.43,6.44h-21.65l-.42.41-8.08,8.08-9.3,9.31-1.28,1.28h-89.17l-7.48-7.48-2.27-2.27-.41-.41h-81.41l-.43-.43-2.39-2.39-10-10-.41-.41H3310.47l-2.13-2.13-10.08-10.08-.41-.42h-44.6L3253,604l-6.21-6.21-8.93-8.93-2.63-2.63,0,0-.37-.37H2822.93v2.83h410.68l.21.21,8.93,8.93L3249,604Z"
            transform="translate(-30.27 -261.21)"
          />
          <polygon
            points="3061.71 179.65 3062.12 180.06 3062.71 180.06 3148.43 180.06 3148.43 179.56 3148.43 177.22 3148.23 177.22 3063.3 177.22 3050.13 164.05 3044.94 158.86 3044.54 158.45 3043.94 158.45 2807.94 157.44 2807.94 156.02 2807.94 153.29 3043.66 153.29 3046.4 156.02 3054.43 164.05 3062.02 171.64 3062.44 172.06 3063.03 172.06 3147.51 172.06 3147.51 170.64 3147.51 169.22 3063.61 169.22 3058.44 164.05 3050.41 156.02 3045.26 150.86 3044.84 150.45 3044.25 150.45 2806.52 150.45 2805.1 150.45 2805.1 151.87 2805.1 156.02 2805.1 158.85 2805.1 160.26 2806.51 160.27 3043.34 161.28 3046.11 164.05 3061.63 179.56 3061.71 179.65"
          />
          <path
            stroke="url(#linear)"
            d="M2836.76,411.93a7.6,7.6,0,0,0-4.33-1.34,7.68,7.68,0,1,0,7.67,7.67,7.57,7.57,0,0,0-.87-3.54,6.32,6.32,0,0,0-.47-.79"
            transform="translate(-30.27 -261.21)"
          />
          <path
            stroke="url(#linear)"
            d="M2612.61,628.36a7.69,7.69,0,0,0-11.15,2.79,7.58,7.58,0,0,0-.87,3.55,7.68,7.68,0,1,0,14.49-3.55c-.15-.27-.3-.54-.47-.79"
            transform="translate(-30.27 -261.21)"
          />
          <path
            stroke="url(#linear)"
            d="M2927.94,500.65a7.7,7.7,0,1,0,2.47,2.79,6.32,6.32,0,0,0-.47-.79"
            transform="translate(-30.27 -261.21)"
          />
          <path
            stroke="url(#linear)"
            d="M3185.56,428.44a7.7,7.7,0,1,0,2.47,2.79,6.21,6.21,0,0,0-.47-.78"
            transform="translate(-30.27 -261.21)"
          />
        </g>
      </svg>
    </div>

    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s probably because from Chromium 75 on, all Chromium browsers are using the dreaded “SwiftShader” which is a graphics software emulation library with the performance of a tortoise!

Although Google says that SwiftShader is only used for WebGL, it seems to slow everything down to unacceptable levels.

There’s no way that I know of to disable SwiftShader and enable the GPU, so get your hands on a Chromium 74 browser which doesn’t have this problem to test and see the difference.